# matching a string using php preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I am stuck.

I am trying to see if an textarea contains an #.

This is what I am trying but it doesnt work.

Example:

```
#firstname# - should trigger "processTaggedMessage"
```

whereas

```
firstname - should trigger "processNormalMessage"
```

The code (PHP):

```
(preg_match("^#(.*?)#$", $msg))
  ? $this->processTaggedMessage($fk_uid, $fk_cid, $sender, $msg, $num, $q)
  : $this->processNormalMessage($fk_uid, $fk_cid, $sender, $msg, $num, $q);
```

I am sure it is probs something simple but I cannot see it, I believe the regex is correct :S

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `^` and `$` if you're trying to match several substrings delimited by `#`.

Use:

```
preg_match('/#.*?#/s', $msg)
```

Comment: Note that using a greedy match (`.*?`) is less efficient that specifying what you don't want to match (`[^#]*`).

Comment: @Daniel: Correction - `.*` is greedy. `.*?` is lazy.

Answer (score 0):

[PCRE regular expressions](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) in PHP need to be [delimited](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). You can try:

```
preg_match('/^#([^#]*)#$/', $msg)
```

Note that `^` and `$` (as per your original pattern) specify that the pattern is [anchored](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to the beginning and end of the string. This means your pattern will not match unless the entire string is `#firstname#`. If you want to search for #'s *within* a string, remove the anchors:

```
preg_match('/#([^#]*)#/', $msg)
```

Also, if you want to ensure that there is some text between the hashes, you should use `+` instead of `*` (`/#([^#]+)#/`). `*` means "zero or more repetitions", whereas `+` means "one or more repetitions".

By the way, since you mentioned in the comments that there are multiple occurrences of what you're searching for within your target string, you'll likely want to use [`preg_match_all`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of `preg_match` so that you can collect all the matches.

Comment: @Daniel V: This didn't seem to match anything. Ty though :D

Comment: @Kyle I'm not sure why it wouldn't match, it's a pretty straightforward pattern and works fine for me... what is the output if you `var_dump($msg)`?

Comment: @Daniel V: Hello #frstname#, your appointment is with #appt# at #time# on #date#.

Comment: @Kyle in that case you don't want your pattern to be anchored. See my update.

Comment: @Daniel V: Thanks for the update, it still doesn't match anything? I must be missing something?

Comment: @Kyle: Again, it works for me (and there's no reason it shouldn't). See [http://www.rubular.com/r/54PrByK24o](http://www.rubular.com/r/54PrByK24o). Perhaps you should update your question with the code you're using?

Comment: @Daniel V: var_dump(preg_match('/#[^#]+)#/', $msg)); throws a Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 6

Comment: @Kyle: looks like I missed the `(` after the first `#`. I've fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_match('/^#(.*?)#$/', $msg)
```

Comment: Example: Hello #frstname#, your appointment is with #appt# at #time# on #date#

Comment: then, your problem is '^' and '$', try without them.
for example, '/^firstname$/' means that firstname match all your string from begining (because ^), to end ($).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (preg_match('/^(.*)#(.*)$/', $msg))
```

and you could also take a look here:

http://php.net/preg_match

and you will find this:

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Comment: The OP is looking for a non-specific string (ie. text situated between two #'s). There is no way to match this efficiently with fixed-string methods like `strpos` or `strstr`.

Comment: the problem was described as "I am trying to see if an textarea contains an #."

Comment: for that you could use if (preg_match('/^(.*)#(.*)#(.*)$/', $msg))

Comment: Maybe I should have been more descriptive. @Stillstanding came up with the correct solution. Ty though